# Individual jquery actions for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the original structure:

```
<div class="out">
 <div class="in">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="out">
 <div class="in">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="out">
 <div class="in">
 </div>
</div>
```

and I add jquery to toggle the "in" div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".in").hide();
    $('.out').hover(function() {
        $(".in").slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

see [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/kfBDJ/1/)

However, it controls all the objects, and I don't know how to perform them individually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use **context selector**

```
$(".in", this).slideToggle(100);
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".in").hide();
    $('.out').hover(function() {
        $(".in", this).slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfBDJ/6/)**

Comment: You do not need $(".in").not(this).hide(); you are already hiding all ".in" elements 2 lines before that

Comment: @Darklizard .. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Make the `.in` selector relative to `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".in").hide();
   $('.out').hover(function() {
       $(this).find(".in").slideToggle(100);
   });
});
```

[Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGJ5T/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".in").hide();
        $('.out').hover(function() {
            $(this).children(".in").slideToggle(100);
    });
});
```

[updated jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/kfBDJ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use **this** as the context selector in the call to jQuery, like this:

```
$(".in",this)
```

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".in").hide();
  $('.out').hover(function() {
    $(".in",this).slideToggle(100);
  });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfBDJ/5/